# How to reads a file into target memory while using DS-5

Tags: arm, ds-5

I am trying to load an ascii file into memory using the command line and I would like to know if there is a command that does it using ARM DS-5 IDE.

I have in the past use the previous ARM tools (RVDS) and been able to perform this task using the readfile command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried a different approach to this issue and ended up loading code by creating an array and assigning an attribute as shown below. This enables you to specify the absolute address of a variable. 
                                                                                                                              
`unsigned int yourArray[] attribute ((at(addressToLoad)))`

[link] http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124981140.htm

Answer (score 3):

The DS-5 `loadfile` and `load` commands will annoyingly only work with executable images because they both demand to know an entry point address. Simply putting arbitrary data (such as your text, or a raw binary like a Linux zImage) into the target's memory is done with very-unintuitive-named `restore` command, with which you *still* have to add the `binary` argument to avoid getting the same error as the others about not understanding the file format.

[ARM Infocenter: DS-5 File-related commands](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0452w/mar1332418574725.html)